# SXA search suggest throws error 500

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I'm trying to implement the Sitecore SXA auto suggest search functionality, below is the setup

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent"> 
 <lst name="suggester"> 
  <str name="name">sxaSuggester</str> 
  <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
  <str name="field">sxacontent_txm</str> 
  <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggester</str> 
  <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str> 
 </lst> 
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" > 
 <lst name="defaults"> 
  <str name="suggest.dictionary">sxaSuggester</str>
  <str name="suggest">true</str> 
  <str name="suggest.count">10</str> 
 </lst> 
 <arr name="components"> 
  <str>suggest</str> 
 </arr> 
</requestHandler>
```

[image]

My Sitecore instance is throwing the below error.

**Error:**

```
    "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage":"The given key was not present in the
dictionary.","ExceptionType":"System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException","StackTrace":"at
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()\r\n at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n at
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Solr.Services.SolrSuggester.GetSuggestions(SuggesterModel model, Timer&
queryTimer, String& indexName)\r\n at
Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.SearchSuggestions(SuggesterModel model)\r\n at
lambda_method(Closure, Object, Object[])\r\n at
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object
        instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at
        System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext,
        IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
        where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at
        System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of
            stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
            System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
            System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at
            System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack
                trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
                System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
                System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of
                    stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
                    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
                    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.
```

Sitecore : 9.2
Solr : 7.5

Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: SXA version 1.9

Comment: You are missing `lookupImpl` parameter in suggester parameters - `<str name="lookupImpl"> FSTLookupFactory</str>`

Comment: Take a look here how the configuration should be corrected -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr-auto-suggest.html#idm46185449656800 and here you can find options for Lookup Implementation -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr-auto-suggest.html#idm46185449646768

Comment: Thanks @PeterProcházka but document says default will be Jaspellookupfactory.

Comment: Hi @PeterProcházka I tried you suggestion but no luck same error.

Comment: After restart, it started working. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the **AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory**  , see below section.

Please note the lookupImpl and dictionaryImpl fields. The `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` is currently supported by SOLR 7.5 - Context filtering lets you filter suggestions by a separate context field, such as category, department or any other token. The AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory and BlendedInfixLookupFactory currently support this feature, when backed by DocumentDictionaryFactory. 
 https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/suggester.html

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">sxaSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">sxacontent_txm</str>
    <str name="contextField">_template</str> 
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Shameless Plug - https://sitecorejumpstart.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sitecore-solr-autosuggest-with-template-and-language-filters/

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Hi @Abhay I tried you suggestion but no luck same error.

Comment: Ok, Did u restart SOLR ?

Comment: Reload the core

Comment: After restart, it started working. thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!. Please accept the answer as well